# Print data in arraylist in ascending order to listview

Tags: android, android-volley

I've an arraylist containing user ids.I want to check the ids in db and have to get the details from mysql through volley and want to print the details in listview in ascending order of id.How can I achieve this?

```
ArrayList<String> absenceids=new ArrayList<>();
Iterator<String> itr=absenceids.iterator();
 while (itr.hasNext()){
           getdetails(itr.next());
         }
```

My getdetails() method :

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response).getJSONArray("Android");

                        int i=jsonResponse.length();

                        for(int j=0;j<i;j++) {
                            JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonResponse.getJSONObject(j);
                          String user_id = jsonChildNode.optString("uid").toString();
                          String rollnum = jsonChildNode.optString("rollnum").toString();
                          String name = jsonChildNode.optString("name").toString();
                          /*  MA_id.add(rollnum);
                            Collections.sort(MA_id);
                            Toast.makeText(AttendenceSave.this, MA_id.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            MA_name.add(name);
                            Collections.sort(MA_name);*/
                           HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<>();
                            contact.put("uid",user_id);
                            contact.put("rollnum",rollnum);
                            contact.put("name", name);

                            Listdetails.add(contact);
                            //CustomListAdapter2 adapter=new CustomListAdapter2(AttendenceSave.this,MA_id,MA_name);
                            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(AttendenceSave.this,Listdetails, R.layout.absenteeslayout, new String[]{"rollnum", "name"}, new int[]{R.id.abroll, R.id.abname});

                            absentees_list.setAdapter(adapter);
                            Utility.setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(absentees_list);
```

Comment: What you tried so far ???

Comment: Please show your efforts

Comment: can you show what you have tried and what is the problem ?

Comment: `How can I achieve this?` I would say, by doing some code.

Answer (score 0):

unsortedList is the input, after the following operation your unsorted list will contain the output with ascending order of ids.

```
Collections.sort(unsortedList,new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String a, String b) {
        return a.compareTo(b);
    }
});
```